# ms excel vba macro userform remove item from listbox1 if it is in listbox2

Tags: excel, vba

I found a lot of things similar to what I need but nothing that works. This code seems to be the closest to what I need but I get error -2147024809 (80070057), invalid argument. I have made sure the rowsource is blank for both listboxes.

```
For Each Item In ListBox2.List
ListBox1.RemoveItem (Item)
Next
```

Help, please! Thanks!

Comment: Item has to be "either an item number or the list item text." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194439.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the listboxes' **RowSource** property is set; you'll recives an Unspecified error. -2147467259 when you try and remove an item.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        For j = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

            If ListBox2.List(i) = ListBox1.List(j) Then
                ListBox1.RemoveItem j
            End If
        Next

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ListBox1.List = Range("List1").Value

    ListBox2.AddItem 1
    ListBox2.AddItem 2
    ListBox2.AddItem 6
    ListBox2.AddItem 7


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas Inzina! Works perfectly!